# CakePHP resources/cheat sheet?

Tags: php, cakephp

Anyone know any CakePHP (or general mvc) resources? I'm trying to learn how to code with CakePHP Framework and it's rather difficult.

Answer (score 12):

[Here is the official manual](http://book.cakephp.org/)

[Here are some training vids](http://tv.cakephp.org/)

[Here are some tutorials](http://devmoose.com/coding/10-awesome-cakephp-tutorials)

[Here are blog tutorials](http://book.cakephp.org/view/219/Blog)

[Here is a cheatsheet](http://cakephp.org/files/Resources/CakePHP-1.2-Cheatsheet.pdf)

[And here](http://support.ongetc.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=254)
... [are some](http://support.ongetc.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=254)
... [resource pages](http://dblog.com.au/web-development/10-helpful-cakephp-resources/)
... [with lots](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/cakephp-resources/)
... [more links](http://junal.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/cakephp-resource-collection-for-newbie/)

Hope that helps get you started :)

Answer (score 6):

Here you can find Complete CakePHP Cheat Sheet For Controller,Views,Models,Email,Caching,Forms
HTML,Paginator,Utilities  and Console
[CakePHP CheatSheet](http://www.cakephpcheatsheet.com/)

[Cake PHP CheatSheet](http://cakephp.org/files/Resources/CakePHP-1.2-Cheatsheet.pdf)

[10 Awesome CakePHP Tutorials](http://devmoose.com/coding/10-awesome-cakephp-tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

This is a official manual for learning CakePHP

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html

to do startup with coding in cakePHP you can read Getting started and Blog Tutorials

hope you can get started with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check the complete cheat sheet for cakephp with little bit updates.
[Cheat Sheet](http://demos.developerhints.com/cakephp-cheat-sheet/)